# Powershell Add XmlElement

Tags: powershell

I have an XML file I'm trying to modify and want to add a new node to an existing config file.  What I'm trying to do is use a multi line xml statement and add it to the XML file by using AppendChild.

Here is what I have so far and I'm getting an error:

```
[xml]$deliveryExtensionNode = @"<Extension Name=`"Database Delivery`">
                        <Configuration>
                    <Reports>
                        <Report>Sample Report</Report>
                    </Reports>
                </Configuration>
                </Extension>
                                "@
```

But I'm getting an error:

Unrecognized token in source text.
At C:\Users\Develer\AppData\Local\Temp\dc32aea8-9f74-4d4f-8237-6219a492ab7a.ps1:17 char:33
+         [xml]$deliveryExtensionNode =  <<<< @"

I thought that Powershell can handle multi line assignments.  I'm able to do the same with something like this:

```
$y = @"
This is a test.
This is another test
"@
```

Or is it because XML requires certain formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@" needs to be on its own line so..

```
[xml]$deliveryExtensionNode = @"
    <Extension Name=`"Database Delivery`">
        <Configuration>
           <Reports>
              <Report>Sample Report</Report>
           </Reports>
        </Configuration>
    </Extension>
    "@
```

Comment: You're right, this is correct.  I did have this exact syntax.  However, I'm using PowerGUI Script Editor and it's freaking out on this exact same syntax.